# Chosen jQuery plugin not working with code igniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have downloaded [the jQuery Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) as I want to implement the simple "multiselect" version. So I've just copied and pasted it in code igniter. I am not a newbie and know almost every thing about how to run jQuery etc.

However I don't know why it is not working on my code igniter, but it works fine without the code igniter.

This is my view page :

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/chosen.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <em>Multiple Select</em>        
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chzn-select" multiple>
        <option value=""></option> 
        <option value="United States">United States</option> 
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
        $(".chzn-select- deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
    </script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

I have checked through Firebug also, the page is loading every script so there is no way that I might have given a wrong path. No error is coming up any where. I don't know what to do.

Comment: You seem to have overlapped `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the chosen plugin before jquery.js, you should in have errors in the console. Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>js/chosen.css" />
```

These lines should also be placed within the `<head>` tag, before the `<body>`

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaks u rock man u rock ... i have been stuck here for almost 3 hours ... u did great ...i dont know i how to say thank you to you .. thankss budy .. god blessed u for helping me

Answer (score 0):

your html is invalid seperate `<head>` and `<body>`..

always call your jquery.js file before your js plugins files

here

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
```

use [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in  the script...i specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

try this (final output)

```
 <head>
  //always load jquery.js frist....
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>js/chosen.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"></script> 
   $(document).ready(function(){  // it is better if u call your function inside document.ready function
     $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
      $(".chzn-select- deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});
   });
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <em>Multiple Select</em>        
     <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chzn-select" multiple>
       <option value=""></option> 
       <option value="United States">United States</option> 
   </select>


</body>
```

Comment: As his jQuery code is at the end of the `body`, document ready handlers are not required.

Comment: yeah thanks for the tip ..this was the actually problem that i was calling jquery file after the plugin files